# Pass by reference and value in C++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I would like to clarify the differences between by value and by reference.

I drew a picture:

[image]

So, for passing by value, a copy of an identical object is created with a different reference, and the local variable is assigned the new reference, so to point to the new copy

How should I understand the following?

> If the function modifies that value, the modifications appear also
> within the scope of the calling function for both passing by value and by reference

Comment: See http://img363.imageshack.us/img363/7202/passbyvaluereferencehg1.jpg

Answer (score 69):

I think much confusion is generated by not communicating what is meant by *passed by reference*. When some people say *pass by reference* they usually mean not the argument itself, but rather *the object being referenced*. Some other say that pass by reference means that the object can't be changed in the callee. Example:

```
struct Object {
    int i;
};

void sample(Object* o) { // 1
    o->i++;
}

void sample(Object const& o) { // 2
    // nothing useful here :)
}

void sample(Object & o) { // 3
    o.i++;
}

void sample1(Object o) { // 4
    o.i++;
}

int main() {
    Object obj = { 10 };
    Object const obj_c = { 10 };

    sample(&obj); // calls 1
    sample(obj) // calls 3
    sample(obj_c); // calls 2
    sample1(obj); // calls 4
}
```

Some people would claim that 1 and 3 are pass by reference, while 2 would be pass by value. Another group of people say all but the last is pass by reference, because the object itself is not copied.

I would like to draw a definition of that here what i claim to be *pass by reference*. A general overview over it can be found here: [Difference between pass by reference and pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-a-parameter-passed-by-reference-vs-passed-by-value#373429). The first and last are pass by value, and the middle two are pass by reference:

```
    sample(&obj);
       // yields a `Object*`. Passes a *pointer* to the object by value. 
       // The caller can change the pointer (the parameter), but that 
       // won't change the temporary pointer created on the call side (the argument). 

    sample(obj)
       // passes the object by *reference*. It denotes the object itself. The callee
       // has got a reference parameter.

    sample(obj_c);
       // also passes *by reference*. the reference parameter references the
       // same object like the argument expression. 

    sample1(obj);
       // pass by value. The parameter object denotes a different object than the 
       // one passed in.
```

I vote for the following definition:

> An argument (1.3.1) is passed by reference if and only if the corresponding parameter of the function that's called has reference type *and* the reference parameter binds directly to the argument expression (8.5.3/4). In all other cases, we have to do with pass by value.

That means that the following is pass by value:

```
void f1(Object const& o);
f1(Object()); // 1

void f2(int const& i);
f2(42); // 2

void f3(Object o);
f3(Object());     // 3
Object o1; f3(o1); // 4

void f4(Object *o);
Object o1; f4(&o1); // 5
```

`1` is pass by value, because it's not directly bound. The implementation may copy the temporary and then bind that temporary to the reference. `2` is pass by value, because the implementation initializes a temporary of the literal and then binds to the reference. `3` is pass by value, because the parameter has not reference type. `4` is pass by value for the same reason. `5` is pass by value because the parameter has not got reference type. The following cases are pass by reference (by the rules of 8.5.3/4 and others):

```
void f1(Object *& op);
Object a; Object *op1 = &a; f1(op1); // 1

void f2(Object const& op);
Object b; f2(b); // 2

struct A { };
struct B { operator A&() { static A a; return a; } };
void f3(A &);
B b; f3(b); // passes the static a by reference
```

Comment: Can you explain  "the reference parameter binds directly to the argument expression"

Comment: if the argument has not the same type or is not a derived class of the parameter, and has no conversion operator to the type of the parameter, then the argument expression does *not* bind directly to the reference parameter.

Comment: also if the argument is an rvalue (like the integer literal 42 in the example). you can find the detailed definition in the standard

Comment: in "void f1(Object const& o); f1(Object());" why is the impl allowed to copy the temporary?

Comment: Iraimbilanja, because the standard says that (read 8.5.3p5). the implementation is allowed to create a copy, but doesn't *have* to do that. in fact, when passing the rvalue (the Object()) to Object's copy constructor it must not do so, to prevent infinite recursion (it would need to copy again :p)

Comment: Since introduction of rvalue references in c++11 saying that a temporary object if passed by value when the argument is of reference type feels very incorrect, an update would be awesome :D

Answer (score 11):

When passing by value:

```
void func(Object o);
```

and then calling

```
func(a);
```

you will construct an `Object` on the stack, and within the implementation of `func` it will be referenced by `o`. This might still be a shallow copy (the internals of `a` and `o` might point to the same data), so `a` might be changed. However if `o` is a deep copy of `a`, then `a` will not change.

When passing by reference:

```
void func2(Object& o);
```

and then calling

```
func2(a);
```

you will only be giving a new way to reference `a`. "`a`" and "`o`" are two names for the same object. Changing `o` inside `func2` will make those changes visible to the caller, who knows the object by the name "`a`".

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.  It is a bit unclear.  However, what might be confusing you is the following:

1. When passing by reference, a reference to the same object is passed to the function being called.  Any changes to the object will be reflected in the original object and hence the caller will see it.
2. When passing by value, the copy constructor will be called.  The default copy constructor will only do a shallow copy, hence, if the called function modifies an integer in the object, this will not be seen by the calling function, but if the function changes a data structure pointed to by a pointer within the object, then this will be seen by the caller due to the shallow copy.

I might have mis-understood your question, but I thought I would give it a stab anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As I parse it, those words are wrong.  It should read "If the function modifies that value, the modifications appear also within the scope of the calling function when passing by reference, but not when passing by value."

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the words "If the function modifies that value, the modifications appear also within the scope of the calling function for both passing by value and by reference" is that they are **an error**.

Modifications made in a called function are **not** in scope of the calling function when passing by value.

Either you have mistyped the quoted words or they have been extracted out of whatever context made what appears to be wrong, right.

Could you please ensure you have correctly quoted your source and if there are no errors there give more of the text surrounding that statement in the source material.