# Is this' type variableofType()' function or object?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
class name
{
public:
    int a;
    name():a(0){};
};
void add(name * pname)
{
    pname = NULL;
}
int main()
{
    name varName();
    name * pName = new name();
    add(pName);
    add(&varName);//error C2664: 'add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'name __cdecl *)(void)' to 'name *'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's worth telling you about a similar problem, that also causes trouble:

```
struct foo { };
struct bar { bar(foo f); };

int main() {
  // does *not* create a bar object initialized by a default constructed 
  // foo object.
  bar b(foo());
}
```

What b really is is a function that returns a `bar` and takes as first argument a pointer to a function that returns a foo taking no arguments. It's the same as:

```
bar b(foo(*)());
```

If you want to create a bar object initialized by a default constructed foo, put parentheses around the argument. That makes it doesn't look like a function declaration anymore, and the compiler will interpret it like you want:

```
bar b((foo()));
```

---

There are also non-obvious cases where a compiler error should be risen. GCC gets this wrong, but Comeau gets it right again. Consider the following snippet

```
struct foo {
  static bool const value = false;
};

int main() {
  int v(int(foo::value));
}
```

You will probably expect that this takes the static constant, and casts it to `int`, initializing the `v` variable to `0`? No, it won't according to the Standard, because the initializer can be interpreted as a declaration, according to pure syntax analysis, as the following shows

```
struct foo {
  static int value;
};

// valid, parentheses are redundant! Defines `foo::value`.
int (foo::value);
```

Whenever the initializer can be interpreted as a declaration, in such a situation whole the declaration will declare a function. So, the line in `main` declares a function like the following, omitting the redundant and meaningless parentheses

```
int v(int foo::value);
```

And this will cause a compiler error when parsing the function declaration, because a function parameter name may not be qualified.

Comment: great answering my next question ...even before asking it

Comment: @litb what determines a function parameter as pass by value or pass by reference is it just function signature or how does the function is called

Comment: rajKumar, i answered the question in the past, trying to set up a definition for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c#410857 . or do you mean something else?

Comment: _that_ is _wicked_!  I didn't know that foo() would be an alias for foo(*)() ... thanks!

Comment: yeah. it's the same in parameter lists only though. otherwise foo() is indeed the type of a function rather than the type of a function pointer (much like char[3] is the type of an array, while char(*)[4] is an array pointer)

Answer (score 22):

The error is on the first line of the main function:

```
name varName();
```

You are **not** creating an instance of class *name* with the default constructor, you are actually declaring a new function called *varName*, with no parameters, which returns a *name* instance.

You should instead write:

```
name varName;
```

Comment: I ran into this one a thousand times!  ;-)

<troll>I think that the C++ language is a successful "meme" (check the Wikipedia): it is successful because it allows developers to feel intelligent when they finally grasp yet another gotcha. It flatters them, that's why they like it.  ;-)
</troll>

Comment: i so much like this sort of question :) it causes a "aha!" effect on the readers, and it gives much points to a right answer :) +1 indeed

Comment: is there any thing similar to this kind of syntax in c++...that one should know abt

Comment: rajKumar, see below for another example

Comment: My mind has been boggled.  I've never run into it in years of C++, but it's a definite +1.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting that your add() function doesn't have any lasting effects -- all it's doing is assigning a value to pname, which is a copy of the pointer you pass into it.  If you want to actually have that assignment stick, you would need to pass the pointer by reference as "name*& pname".

Answer (score 0):

```
name varName();
```

is interpreted as a local function declaration.  To invoke the default constructor, use

```
name varName;
```

instead.  Most vexing, yes.