# What is the difference when I write Func1(int &a) and Func1(int *a)?

Tags: c++, windows, pass-by-reference, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Difference between pointer variable and reference variable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

As I am starting with C++, I found the operation below confusing. I got to know about passing by reference and passing by value. But recently I came across functions like this which confused me:

```
Func1(int &a)
Func2(int *a)
```

Both of the functions expect the address of *a*, but when I call Func1 I do that by `Func1(a)` and in case of Func2, I call by `Func2(&a)`.

How come Func1 is accepting *int a* directly while it is expecting the address of *a*?

Comment: Related: *[Pass by reference and value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)* and [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value#373429)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Func1(int &a)
// It accepts arguments by reference.
// Changes to an inside Func1 are reflected in the caller.
// 'a' cannot bind to an Rvalue, e.g., it can't call Func1(5)
// 'a' can never be referring to something that is not a valid object

Func2(int *a)
// It accepts arguments by value.
// Change to an inside Func1 is not reflected in the caller, and changes to *a are
// 'a' can bind to an Rvalue, e.g., Func1(&localvar).
// 'a' can be NULL. Hence Func2 may need to check if 'a' is NULL.
```

Answer (score 7):

When providing an argument for a pass-by-reference parameter, the compiler will do the necessary & operation behind the scenes. You, as the programmer, know that it is internally using the address of your argument, but this is hidden in the pass-by-reference abstraction. This is safer than using a pointer as you cannot inadvertently reassign a reference.

Comment: also, you're saving yourself the trouble of checking for `nullptr`.

Answer (score 5):

Internally, there's not much difference. But one is a reference, and the other one is a pointer. The primary difference is that you can't modify the reference in your function, so the reference will always point to `a`.

I.e.,

```
void func1(int &a) {
    a = 5;
}
```

This will modify `a`, i.e., whichever variable the caller pointed to.

```
void func2(int *a) {
    *a = 5;   // Same effect as the above code
    a = &b;   // You couldn't do that with a reference
}
```

Comment: `a = &b` only changes `a` local to the function. You would need a pointer to a pointer to change it once it leaves the function.

Comment: That's not the point. You could do another `*a = 5` afterwards, which would modify a different address. That's not possible with a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, when you have a *&something* you have a reference and this is nothing more than a pointer which cannot change. In other words, it is a *const* pointer, so basically it’s like **something*, but in this case you can change the pointer (to point somewhere else) :)

A quick example:

Reference: `Object &obj`

The same written with pointer syntax: `Object* const obj`

Answer (score 1):

Func1 will take a reference to an *int*, and Func2 will take a pointer to an *int*. When you do *Func2(&someint)*, you're giving the function the address of *someint*. This address can be dereferenced to get its value. When you "pass by value" Func1(int someint), then, a copy of *someint* is performed. When you pass either by reference, or by pointer, no such copy is performed.

A reference can be thought of, as essentially an "alias" to the original value, or, another way of referring to it. Yes, it's abstract, but, everything else is implementation-specific and not for you to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

In `Func1(int &a)`, `&a` is the reference to the variable that you will be passing.

In `Func2(int *a)`, `*a` is the pointer to address of the variable that you will be passing by its address.

Comment: What? Func1(int &a) is the function declaration. You're declaring a function that will take a reference to an int. When calling Func1, you would not say int &a, you would say &a, in which case, yes, you would get the address of the int(and this would be invalid with the above declaration, because the function takes a reference to an int, not an intptr). Can't believe this actually got two upvotes.

Comment: @ John I never said to call the with function with &a, I'm stating the meaning of &a in either function declaration or definition.

Comment: Except, in the function declaration, int &a means you'll be passing in a reference-to-int to the function. &a means "address of a" only when used outside function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

When the function definition is Func1(int &a), it means this function will accept the address of the variable which will pass to this function as a parameter. (So you don't need to take care of passing the address of the variable which will a parameter to the function). The function default behavior will be to get the address of the passed variable.

E.g.,

```
Func1(int &a){
   a = 5; // 'a' will store 5 at &a
}

Func1(a) // We don't need to pass &a. The function definition will take care of this.
```

===================================================================

Whereas if the function definition is Func2(int *a), it means it will hold the address of the given value. That means you must have to pass &a in the function call as a parameter, which will be later stored as in *a in the function definition.

E.g.,

```
Fun2(int *a){
   *a = 7; // a will store 7 at &a
}
```

Function call: Fun2(&a); Must have to pass &a. The function definition will *not* take care of this.

Answer (score -1):

It is not like that.

1. `Func1(int &a)` - when you call this function, `Func1(a)` which will pass the *int* only there, the function receives the address of the passing argument.
2. `Func2(int *a)` - when you call this function with `Func2(&a)`, this statement just passes the reference of '`a`'. In the called function argument '`*a`' which will gain the value which is referring that calling function's parameter '`&a`'.