# How to calculate look at point to move the camera with the mouse in OpenGL/GLUT?

Tags: opengl, camera, mouse, move, glut

This will be confusing for me to explain so please bear with me.

I've already implemented most type of movements and rotations in my camera class, everything is working with the keyboard, now I want to implement the mouse. I capture the mouse movement like this:

```
#define SENSITIVITY 25.0f

void main(void) {
    (...)
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(processPassiveMotion);    
    glutWarpPointer(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2);
    glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
    (...)
}

void processPassiveMotion(int x, int y) {
    int centerX = WINDOW_WIDTH / 2;
    int centerY = WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2;

    int deltaX = -1 * (x - centerX);
    int deltaY = -1 * (y - centerY);

    if(deltaX != 0 || deltaY != 0) {
        mainCamera.Rotate(deltaX / SENSITIVITY, deltaY / SENSITIVITY);

        glutWarpPointer(centerX, centerY);
    }
}
```

After everything I've read, I believe this is enough in my situation. However I must state that first I tried to call the `Pitch()` and `Yaw()` camera functions but it was a no go, I had to create an extra function to rotate both axis "at the same time".

That rotate function goes something like this:

```
#define DEG2RAD(a) (a * (M_PI / 180.0f))
#define SINDEG(a)  sin(DEG2RAD(a))
#define COSDEG(a)  cos(DEG2RAD(a))

void Camera::Rotate(GLfloat angleX, GLfloat angleY) {
    Reference = NormalizeVector(
        Reference * COSDEG(angleY) + UpVector * SINDEG(angleY)
    );

    Reference = NormalizeVector(
        Reference * COSDEG(angleX) - RightVector * SINDEG(angleX)
    );

    UpVector = CrossProduct(&Reference, &RightVector) * (-1);
    RightVector = CrossProduct(&Reference, &UpVector);
}
```

The `Reference` is the viewing direction, the point the camera is looking at. And since it's a normalized vector, it goes from -1.0 to 1.0. This vector, or point, is later used together with another vector (`Position`, which is the camera location) to calculate the real look at point to use in `gluLookAt`, like this:

```
void Camera::LookAt(void) {
    Vector3D viewPoint = Position + Reference;

    gluLookAt(
        Position.x, Position.y, Position.z,
        viewPoint.x, viewPoint.y, viewPoint.z,
        UpVector.x, UpVector.y, UpVector.z
    );
}
```

All vector operations above like `+`, `-` and `*` are overloaded of course.

Now I'm going to try to describe my problem...

The rotate function above works just fine in the sense that it correctly performs a pitch and yaw by using the mouse. However, those rotations don't look like the ones in First Person Shooter games. In those games, when one looks at sky and then looks left/right, one expects to keep looking at the sky. Imagining we are inside a sphere, a movement like that should "draw" a circle in the top part of the sphere.

But that's not what happens because that's not what a yaw does. A yaw movement will rotate around an arbitrary axis, which I think is the up vector in this situation. So, the  problem is in the yaw movement because the pitch seems to work fine.

In other words, my code above can't keep the horizon leveled and that's what must happen cause that's happens in games when one looks at the sky and then look left/right, the horizon is always leveled. The same will not happen with my code, I look up and then left/right, and the horizon will be all twisted.

Did I make myself clear enough? I'm not sure how can I explain this any better. :( Hopefully it's enough for anyone to understand.

I'm not sure how can I fix this problem... How can I look left/right correctly after looking up/down, keeping the horizon leveled?

**EDIT:**

My rotate function code is taken from both the Yaw and Pitch functions which also exist so I can call those rotations independently. For reference purposes I'll add them below along with the Roll function too (which I'll probably never use, but in case I need it, it's there):

```
void Camera::Pitch(GLfloat angle) {
    Reference = NormalizeVector(
        Reference * COSDEG(angle) + UpVector * SINDEG(angle)
    );

    UpVector = CrossProduct(&Reference, &RightVector) * (-1);
}

void Camera::Yaw(GLfloat angle) {
    Reference = NormalizeVector(
        Reference * COSDEG(angle) - RightVector * SINDEG(angle)
    );

    RightVector = CrossProduct(&Reference, &UpVector);
}

void Camera::Roll(GLfloat angle) {
    RightVector = NormalizeVector(
        RightVector * COSDEG(angle) - UpVector * SINDEG(angle)
    );

    UpVector = CrossProduct(&Reference, &RightVector) * (-1);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem appears to be in the statement:

```
UpVector = CrossProduct(&Reference, &RightVector) * (-1);
```

Once you've rotated Reference toward RightVector in the previous statement, their cross product will no longer result in an UpVector that gives you a horizontal horizon.  Try it with your arms.  Furthermore, Reference and RightVector are not separated by 90 degrees, so UpVector won't even be a unit vector either.  (Finally, you should really just switch the order of the cross product for clarity, rather than multiplying by (-1).)

Honestly, if I were doing it, I would take a different approach.  I don't see any logical reason why the two rotations have to be in one function.  I also avoid explicit sines and cosines at all costs when working with vectors.  I think what you really need is a function to [Rotate About an Arbitrary Axis](http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/ArbitraryAxisRotation.html).  If nothing else, it's *very* useful.  Fortunately all the details are taken care of by Mr. Murray!  If you implement this function, then it becomes very simple.  Define a constant `SkyVector` that always points upward.  Then in pseudocode,

```
AxisRotation( Vector vec, Vector axis, float angle ) {
    Vector result;

    // The axis is assumed to be normalized:  
    //    (just make sure you're not modifying the original)
    axis = NormalizeVector( &axis );

    // expanded for clarity:
    float u = axis.x;
    float v = axis.y;
    float w = axis.z;
    float x = vec.x;
    float y = vec.y;
    float z = vec.z;
    float c = cos(angle);
    float s = sin(angle);

    // Apply the formula verbatim from the linked page:
    result.x = u*(u*x + v*y + w*z)*(1.-c) + x*c + (-w*y + v*z)*s;
    result.y = v*(u*x + v*y + w*z)*(1.-c) + y*c + ( w*x - u*z)*s;
    result.z = w*(u*x + v*y + w*z)*(1.-c) + z*c + (-v*x + u*y)*s;

    return result;
}

Yaw(angleX) {
    Reference = AxisRotation( &Reference, &SkyVector, angleX );
    RightVector = NormalizeVector( CrossProduct( &Reference, &SkyVector ) );
    UpVector = CrossProduct( &RightVector, &Reference );
}

Pitch(angleY) {
    Reference = AxisRotation( &Reference, &RightVector, angleY );
    //RightVector doesn't change!
    UpVector = CrossProduct( &RightVector, &Reference );
}
```

If you go through that operation by operation, it should hopefully make some sense.  Finally, I'll add that [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) are really the 'correct' way to do this stuff and avoid [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), but I usually do pretty much exactly what you've done.  You might have to check every now and then to make sure your vectors stay nice and perpendicular.  Quaternions are more stable.

**Edit:** If the axis rotation function is overkill, you can still implement this with simple vectors and rotation matrices.  The only thing is you'll have to start projecting things into the horizontal plane so that you can do the two rotations independently  And it'll still take some sines and cosines.  Your time is probably better spent implementing the axis rotation function!

Comment: A couple of points: 1) I'll be honest and tell you that although I understand a few of the concepts involved in all this, I didn't implement the code above myself (http://www.codecolony.de/docs/camera2.htm), which means I'm not sure I can implement that function myself. 2) Both rotations are in one function just for clarification, I have 3 separate functions (for Pitch, Yaw and Roll). I've added them to the question, do you think they need to redone too?

Comment: 3) Yes, I keep reading about quaternions but that's too hard for me to implement and really don't want to scrap everything I have and go a different route. Not for now at least, in the future, if this issue becomes really important to me, I'll dig into it. 4) If I know exactly what's Gimbal Lock, I think the code above prevents that. Might not be the 'correct' way to do it, but it solves the issue. 4) What do you mean by checking "every now and then to make sure your vectors stay nice and perpendicular"? What, where and when exactly should I check that?

Comment: Your code does prevent that.  When you look straight up, you can still yaw gracefully, but the horizon won't stay level.  It's one or the other.  And I agree.  I implemented [quaternions](http://www.genesis3d.com/~kdtop/Quaternions-UsingToRepresentRotation.htm) once, but never finished debugging it.

Comment: When I say they must remain perpendicular, I only mean that if you rotate vectors independently by the same transformation over and over, floating point errors may creep in and they could diverge from being perpendicular.  Dot(x,y), dot(y,z) and dot(x,z) should be very close to zero.  If not, you need to do some cross products and re-perpendicularize them.  It's as simple as overwriting z=cross(x,y), then y=cross(z,x).

Comment: Yeah, it works, thank you so much. But I still have a few questions/small problems. This is not a forum so it's turning to be difficult to discuss this. If you don't mind, I'll post a link to a text code file with all the relevant code and comment where I have questions, I promise it's a just a few. I've enumerated my questions to make it easier to answer. Sorry for the capitalization, it's just to separate my questions from the code. Here's the link: http://pastebin.com/UqjA6WU5 (Pastebin Edited #1)

Comment: Damn, I was editing the pastebin once again but you're too quick... Here's a new version with the relevant edits, everything you already answered was removed. Although I probably know the answers already, here it is: http://pastebin.com/ZWHKKc8t

Comment: Yes, Yes, and Yes.  It jumps because of the singularity.  You should still be careful since 'yaw' isn't a true yaw and the constraint that the camera should point upward conflicts with 'roll.'  Again, I can only advise you to consider which behavior you want and try to make it happen.  There's no correct answer.  The requirements of a 3D modeler are different than the requirements of a flight simulator are different than the requirements of a first-person shooter.

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. I just want to have all the possibilities there in case I need them. For now I don't need roll at all, but if I did, I would just switch back from `SkyVector` to `UpVector`, but then the horizon wouldn't be leveled. It's fine, I understand the restrains on the type of camera I choose. I can't thank you enough for all your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: One last thing unrelated to the the question, what do you mean by "by c++-style reference"? Is there a difference to just C? This is actually my first time working with C++ and in a very basic level, I don't seem any differences in how structs, pointers, passing by val/ref works. I've been coding in C for a while now and C++ seems pretty much the same syntax wise (ignoring classes, namespaces, ATL/MFC and stuff like that). Am I missing anything important?

Comment: passing a pointer != passing by reference.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow… I don't think I would have ever found this on my own. I was trying to do the exact same thing, thanks @Ricky!

Comment: @Mk12 - I'm equally shocked that something I said was useful!