# What exactly is the difference between "pass by reference" in C and in C++?

Tags: c++, c, terminology, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

The phrase "pass by reference" is used by C and C++ developers alike but they appear to be used to mean different things. What exactly is the difference between this equivocal phrase in each language?

Comment: Despite there being some similar questions and answers, I was surprised to not find an answer that actually covers this (in particular, an in-depth discussion of the differences between C and C++). It is a common misunderstanding, especially for the many people who, for some reason, learnt C and C++ simultaneously or who transferred from one to the other. I think many problems for novice C and C++ programmers stem from the confusion between what exactly is happening in each language.

Comment: Did you ever read the most upvoted answer to [Pass by Reference / Value in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)?

Comment: @JesseGood I did, but I'm trying to target the differences between the two languages and when one should use the phrases in the two contexts. I felt like my question was reasonably different, although the answer contains some duplicate content.

Comment: @stfrabbit: Note how the linked answer makes a distinction between bound temporaries, which is a little different from your answer.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There are questions that already deal with [the difference between passing by reference and passing by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/150634). In essence, passing an argument by value to a function means that the function will have its own copy of the argument - its *value* is copied. Modifying that copy will not modify the original object. However, when passing by reference, the parameter inside the function *refers to* the same object that was passed in - any changes inside the function will be seen outside.

Unfortunately, there are two ways in which the phrases "pass by value" and "pass by reference" are used which can cause confusion. I believe this is partly why pointers and references can be difficult for new C++ programmers to adopt, especially when they've come from a background in C.

## C

In C, everything is passed by value in the technical sense. That is, whatever you give as an argument to a function, it will be copied into that function. For example, calling a function `void foo(int)` with `foo(x)` copies the value of `x` as the parameter of `foo`. This can be seen in a simple example:

```
void foo(int param) { param++; }

int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  foo(x);
  printf("%d\n",x); // x == 5
}
```

The value of `x` is copied into `foo` and that copy is incremented. The `x` in `main` continues to have its original value.

As I'm sure you're aware, objects can be of pointer type. For example, `int* p` defines `p` as a pointer to an `int`. It is important to note that the following code introduces two objects:

```
int x = 5;
int* p = &x;
```

The first is of type `int` and has the value `5`. The second is of type `int*` and its value is the address of the first object.

When passing a pointer to a function, you are still passing it by value. The address it contains is copied into the function. Modifying that *pointer* inside the function will not change the pointer outside the function - however, modifying *the object it points to* will change the object outside the function. But why?

As two pointers that have the same value always point at the same object (they contain the same address), the object that is being pointed to may be accessed and modified through both. This gives the semantics of having passed the pointed to object by reference, although no references ever actually existed - there simply are no references in C. Take a look at the changed example:

```
void foo(int* param) { (*param)++; }

int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  foo(&x);
  printf("%d\n",x); // x == 6
}
```

We can say when passing the `int*` into a function, that the `int` it points to was "passed by reference" but in truth the `int` was never actually passed anywhere at all - only the pointer was copied into the function. This gives us the colloquial<sup>1</sup> meaning of "pass by value" and "pass by reference".

The usage of this terminology is backed up by terms within the standard. When you have a pointer type, the type that it is pointing to is known as its *referenced type*. That is, the referenced type of `int*` is `int`.

> A *pointer type* may be derived from a function type, an object type, or an incomplete
>   type, called the *referenced type*.

While the unary `*` operator (as in `*p`) is known as indirection in the standard, it is commonly also known as dereferencing a pointer. This further promotes the notion of "passing by reference" in C.

## C++

C++ adopted many of its original language features from C. Among them are pointers and so this colloquial form of "passing by reference" can still be used - `*p` is still dereferencing `p`. However, using the term will be confusing, because C++ introduces a feature that C doesn't have: the ability to truly pass *references*.

A type followed by an ampersand is a *reference type*<sup>2</sup>. For example, `int&` is a reference to an `int`. when passing an argument to a function that takes reference type, the object is truly passed by reference. There are no pointers involved, no copying of objects, no nothing. The name inside the function actually refers to exactly the same object that was passed in. To contrast with the example above:

```
void foo(int& param) { param++; }

int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  foo(x);
  std::cout << x << std::endl; // x == 6
}
```

Now the `foo` function has a parameter that is a reference to an `int`. Now when passing `x`, `param` refers to precisely the same object. Incrementing `param` has a visible change on the value of `x` and now `x` has the value 6.

In this example, nothing was passed by value. Nothing was copied. Unlike in C, where passing by reference was really just passing a pointer by value, in C++ we can genuinely pass by reference.

Because of this potential ambiguity in the term "pass by reference", it's best to only use it in the context of C++ when you are using a reference type. If you are passing a pointer, you are not passing by reference, you are passing a pointer by value (that is, of course,  unless you are passing a reference to a pointer! e.g. `int*&`). You may, however, come across uses of "pass by reference" when pointers are being used, but now at least you know what is really happening.

---

### Other languages

Other programming languages further complicate things. In some, such as Java, every variable you have is known as a reference to an object (not the same as a reference in C++, more like a pointer), but those references are passed by value. So even though you appear to be passing to a function by reference, what you're actually doing is copying a reference into the function by value. This subtle difference to passing by reference in C++ is noticed when you assign a new object to the reference passed in:

```java
public void foo(Bar param) {
  param.something();
  param = new Bar();
}
```

If you were to call this function in Java, passing in some object of type `Bar`, the call to `param.something()` would be called on the same object you passed in. This is because you passed in a reference to your object. However, even though a new `Bar` is assigned to `param`, the object outside the function is still the same old object. The new one is never seen from the outside. That's because the reference inside `foo` is being reassigned to a new object. This kind of reassigning references is impossible with C++ references.

---

<sup>1</sup> By "colloquial", I don't mean to suggest that the C meaning of "pass by reference" is any less truthful than the C++ meaning, just that C++ really does have reference types and so you are genuinely passing by *reference*. The C meaning is an abstraction over what is really passing by value.

<sup>2</sup> Of course, these are lvalue references and we now have rvalue references too in C++11.

Comment: *"there simply is no true pass by reference in C"* -- This is wrong.  Your definition of passing by reference is biased toward C++.  The term "passing by reference" predates C++.  It is done in different ways in different languages.  In C, passing a pointer to an object is, infact, passing that object by reference.  Actually, it is in C++ too.  It just happens that C++ has two ways of passing by reference.

Comment: It should say: In some, such as Java, every variable you have is a pointer to an object (called a reference, but absolutely not the C++ meaning of reference). This is exactly identical to passing a pointer to an object in C++. "passing in some object of type Bar" You are confusing yourself here. Objects cannot be passed and are not values in Java.

Comment: so basically
c: pass a pointer by value  ,  
c++: pass by reference

Comment: By saying, passing a reference will not make copy could be wrong, as most compilers internally implement references as constant pointers which are automatically de-referenced, so when you are passing a reference to the function it will make a copy.

Comment: @vinodsaluja Can you plz explain how then changing that c++ reference (allais) can be seen outside too? Does this mean compiler sync and copy this new value to the original memory??!