# How can I overwrite the data in an element of an array of structures?

Tags: android, c

So, I have this structure:

```
typedef struct{
    int serialNumber;
    char name[100];
    float price;
    int quantity;
 }Products;
```

And I created an array of structures dynamically.

The task was to 'simulate' a grocery store, with the user able to add and edit the items sold by the store. The following code snippets are for editing structure data.

```
void overwrite(Products store){
   printf("Enter new serial number: ");
   scanf("%d", &(store.serialNumber));

   getchar();

   printf("Enter new product name: ");
   fgets(store.name, 100, stdin);
   store.name[strlen(store.name)-1]='\0';

   printf("Enter new product price: ");
   scanf("%f", &(store.price));

   printf("Enter new product quantity: ");
   scanf("%d", &(store.quantity));
 }

void editData(Products *store, int storeCapacity){ //storeCapacity needed to invoke printData(), assume a working code for the function.

  int choice;

  printData(store, storeCapacity);
  printf("Enter slot number of product here: ");
  scanf("%d", &choice);

  overwrite(store[choice]);
}
```

Here's the catch, even though this code works, when I try to print the data, the data displays the values which should be overwritten. Have I forgotten to do something? I wish you could help me.

BTW, I code on an Android phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the difference between "pass by reference" in C and in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654138/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-pass-by-reference-in-c-and-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
void overwrite(Products store){
```

C is pass by value, you need to pass a pointer to `Products` (i.e., `Products *store`) and modify the `overwrite` call in `editData` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem is that in C you pass arguments by value. So when you specify this signature

```
void overwrite(Products store)
```

and you invoke it somewhere:

```
Products myStore;
overwrite(myStore);
```

what happens is that a copy of `myStore` is created and placed on the stack, then the value is passed to the function. This means that every modification done to the `Products` object inside `overwrite` applies on the passed copy, not on the original object. This copy is then discarded when exiting the scope of `overwrite` function.

To solve this problem you must pass a pointer to the object, that is passed by value but being an address will point to the exact same `myStore` object. This is done in this way:

```
void overwrite(Products* store)
{
  ..
  scanf("%f", &store->price);
  ..
}

Products myStore;
overwrite(&myStore);
```

Comment: What's the point to answer after requesting to close as duplicate?

Comment: @ouah: If the question gets closed it's irrelevant if I answered or not, since I spent my time answering I don't see your point. I would argue: what's the point of answering to a question obviously already asked before without searching for a duplicate and marking it, as you did.

Comment: For your question, simple, my point is not to explain or re-explain the pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference, my goal is to spot the bug in his code and to show to OP where it is.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ouah, I passed the structure as the value itself, which did happen in my code.

So what I did is...

```
void overwrite(Products * store){ //formal parameter changed into a pointer
  //codes here
}
```

And...

```
overwrite(&(store[choice])); /* actual parameter changed into a pointer by affixing ampersand*/
```

Further explanations of the codes' misbehavior were explained by Jack. I extend my gratitudes to you. The code now worked as it should be.