# Can't understand class constructor

Tags: c++, class, reference, constructor

I have a class.

```
class Books
{
private:
    int m_books;
public:
    Books(int books=0)
    {
        m_books = books;
    }

    Books(const Books &source)  //Here is what I don't understand.
    {
        m_books = source.m_books;
    }
};
```

I can't understand why it has to be `Books(const Books &source)`, and not `Books(const Books source)`.

Comment: sorry web browser messed code up somehow :/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Books(const Books &source)
```

means that a reference is passed, instead of the actual variable (as in pass-by-value, as in the case of primitives such as `int` or `char`).

In this case, since you are building a copy constructor, you don't want to make modification to the object whose reference is passed in, so the argument signature is prefixed with `const` (this guarantees that the argument being passed in is immutable)

(**Note, mostly importantly:** pass-by-value here would introduce infinite recursion - see @AProgrammer's answer) Aside from that, it also would be unnecessarily expensive to pass in `source` by value (meaning: make a copy of the entire source when the copy constructor is called), we just use a reference instead.

---

Additional reading you might be interested in: [C++ Pass by Reference vs. Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)

Comment: @sampson-chen, yes I posted my comment and then noticed that you updated. I removed it now.   Regarding "unnecessarily expensive" - it sort of pointless to mention in the context of copy constructor, because it's simply impossible to do.

Answer (score 9):

When you have

```
Books(const Books &source)
```

the source is passed by reference.  When you have

```
Books(const Books source)
```

it would have been passed by value.  But to pass by value you are the copy constructor. So to avoid an infinite recursion, the copy constructor **must** accept a reference.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking at is called the copy constructor. The reason why you should pass an object by a reference is because if you pass it by a value then a copy of the object has to be constructed, so it would have to call the copy constructor again. And again. And again ...

Answer (score 1):

So book is passed by reference instead of copied by value.

Comment: Thank you too for quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a reference means that there's no copy involved. If you had:

```
Books(const Books source)
```

Then the argument the caller passes would have to be copied to `source`. If you use a reference instead, no copy is made. This provides better performance. With small amounts of data it doesn't matter much, because it's a simple class with no large amount of data. But with more complex classes, copying can be expensive. Using references avoids that problem.

However, in the case of copy constructors, avoiding a copy is vital. Not for performance reasons, but by the fact that copying involves a copy constructor. When the copy constructor gets called, another copy would have to be made if a reference was not used. That means another call to a copy constructor. There, yet another copy would have to be made. Yet another call to a copy constructor.

As you can imagine, this would result in an infinite amount of copy constructor calls. By using a reference this situation is avoided.

Comment: it not about performance, it about avoiding infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Read about copy constructors: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

Answer (score 0):

It is passing in a reference to the `Books source` object. That it all.

I hope this helps.