# Passing a variable to a class method

Tags: c++

I have a method called update in a class called Man. In my main.cpp I call:

```
int age=0;
Man person;
person.Update(age);
```

This updates the person's age in the method. However, when I come back to the main file, it does not have an updated age. So the variable is set in the class method but not getting back to the main.cpp context.

## EDIT

```
Man::Update(int age)
{
    age++;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code for "person::update"

Comment: Does Update() take a reference? I'm guessing not.

Comment: What do you mean by a reference?

Comment: Why `age` not an attribute of `Man`?

Comment: That's a bad example. :-) Why would a man update an age? Except perhaps his own in `celebrate_birthday()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a change in a variable to be reflected back in the calling scope, a reference to the variable has to be passed to the function. When a reference is passed, the variable in the function scope effectively refers to / is the variable in the calling scope.

```
Man::Update(int &age) //The ampersand reflects that it is a reference
{
    age++;
}
```

What you are doing is called passing by value. In this case, a new copy of the variable is created in the function scope and any changes made are not reflected back in the calling scope.

Look at this for a [detailed explanation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/) and this for a [Q&A style explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c).

However, what you are doing in this specific case, does not require classes or member functions at all. It can be done using a single *normal* function.

Answer (score 3):

```
void Man::Update(int & age)
{
   age++;
}
```

it should work

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the `age` argument *by value*. This means that it is copied into the function `Update` and that copy is modified. You need to pass the argument *by reference*. This is easily done in C++ because it provides reference types. A name with reference type acts as an alias for the object that it is bound to. All you have to do is add an ampersand (`&`) to your type:

```
void Man::Update(int& age)
{
  age++;
}
```

When you do `person.Update(age);` you are binding the object `age` to the reference `age` in your function.

Others may give you an alternative method using pointers (take an `int*` argument and pass `&age` to the function). This is how it would be done in C - but we're not writing C. Don't let them fool you! Taking a reference type is safer and more expressive than using pointers.

However, I question why you have a class called `Man` and `age` is not a member of `Man`. Classes are a way to store related data together as an object. I would consider age to be part of the data that represents a man.

Comment: It's an example of an anti-pattern.