# Usage of multidimensional vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I was trying to use multidimensional `vector` and change the values of row and column.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void changerow(vector<vector<int> > A, int row, int M, int P){
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
        (A[row - 1])[j] = ((A[row - 1])[j] + P) % 10;

    }
}

void changecolumn(vector<vector<int> > A, int column, int N, int P){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        (A[i])[column - 1] = ((A[i])[column - 1] + P) % 10;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int T, N, M;
    cin >> T >> N >> M;
    if((T >= 1 && T <= 10) && (M >= 1 && M <= 100) && (N >= 1 && N <= 100)){
        // Logic of the program
        vector<vector<int> > A(N, vector<int>(M));

        for(int i = 0; i < N ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
                cin >> (A[i])[j];
            }
        }
        changerow(A,2,M,3);
        for(int i = 0; i < N ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
                cout << A[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how would pass the address of the vector in order to change the element, since only the local copy of the vector gets passed.  I am currently reading `Thinking in C++ Volume 1` but its not elaborate. Kindly let me know a good source for learning the use of `vector`s in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are passing the vector *by value*, which means that the callee gets a copy of the vector.

If you wish the changes that the callee makes to be visible to the caller, you need to pass the vector *by reference*. This is done like so:

```
void changecolumn(vector<vector<int> >& A, int column, int N, int P){
                                      ^ THIS
```

For a discussion, see [Pass by Reference / Value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)

Comment: I knew the concept of reference but I did not know the syntax to be used with `vector`. Can you also recommend any source for learning vectors?

Comment: @mozart: I liked Accelerated C++ when it came out, but I suppose it is a little dated now. I am not sure what current introductory books there are out there.

Comment: @mozart, "Effective STL" by Scott Meyers is a great source of info on C++ standard library, including vectors. It's a bit difficult sometimes, but if you fight through, you'll know everything you need.

Comment: @mozart, still you really need to get more fluent with references, so you can pick any good book from this list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list, if your book doesn't cover the subject enough.