# C++: calling function from vector object in main

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to call `printTotals()` from `main()`.  I tried `person.printTotals()` but it does not work because agent only calls functions within the `vector` STL.  I checked other answers, such as [C++ Calling Vectors from Function to Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843253/) and [Using vector of user defined class type objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979894/) and [How to create a vector of class objects in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919277/).

I also checked my STL book, but this case it is not in there.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to call `printTotals()` outside of the constructor?  Can I call it from `main()`?  I want to keep my code clean and modular, but I am unable to access it outside of the constructor.
2. Each `person` has 3 neighbors consisting of `Person`s in a `vector`.  I thought about declaring the `neighbors` vector like this, but was not sure:

   ```
   vector<Person> neighbor
   ```

For a specific person with id = 3, how can I retrieve their second neighbor's voting status?  Would it be:

```
    person[3].neighbor[1].getPersonVotingStatus()?
```

This is my code:

Person.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

class Person
{
   public: 
     Person();
     Person( std::vector<Person> person, maxPersons);
     std::string getPersonVotingStatus(int ID);
     void printTotals();

  private:
    std::string personName;
    float personHeight;
    int personID;
    std::string isVoter;
    vector<Person>neighbor;  // <--- 
}
```

Person.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>


Person::Person()
{}

Person::Person(int pID, float pHeight, std::string pName, std::string isV)
{
    personID = pID;
    personHeight = pHeight;
    personName = pName;
    isVoter = isV;
}

Person::Person( std::vector<Person> person, int maxPersons)
{
    for(int = 0; i < maxPersons; i++)
    {
       person[i].personID = i;
       person[i].personHeight = i + 100;
       person[i].personName = "testName";

       if (i / 2 = 0) { 
          person[i].isVoter = "yes";
       }
       else {
          person[i].isVoter = "no";
       }
   }
           Person(person[i].personID, person[i].personHeight, person[i].personName, person[i].isVoter);

}

std::String getPersonVotingStatus( int ID)
{
    return person[i].isVoter;
}

void printTotals( std::vector<Person> person)
{
   int totalVoter = 0;
   int totalNonvoter = 0;
   
   for (int i = 0; i< person.size(); i++)
      if (person[i].isVoter == "yes") {
        totalVoter++;
   }
   else {
     totalNonvoter++;
  }  
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  int maxPersons = 10;

  std::vector<Person> person;
  Person obj( person, maxPersons);

  person.printTotals(); // <--

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Non-static member functions act on an OBJECT, not the type.     So you (in `main()`) can do `obj.printTotals()` or you can iterate over elements of `person` and call the member function of each one  e.g.  `for (Person &individual : person)  individual.printTotals();`

Comment: Note: It doesn't work is useless information. If it worked, you wouldn't be asking the question, would you? Instead reproduce the error (cut and paste it as text into the question) or the misbehaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `printTotals()` as a static function:

```
class Person
{
   public: 
     static void printTotals(std::vector<Person> person);
}
```

Then you can call it in main like this:

```
Person::printTotals(person);
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be a static function, a free-standing function will work. But you should pass in the vector by reference, not by value.