# Custom class resetting variable back to original value every time method is called

Tags: c++

in my class, I have two methods that are responsible for getting and setting the value of a private variable. In another method that is outside of the class, I call the setter method and change the variable to another value. It works temporarily but always resets to the original value.

```
class storeItem
{
    public:
        void setPrice(int p)
        {
            price = p;
        }
        int getPrice()
        {
            return price;
        }
        storeItem(int p)
        {
            price = p;
        }
    private:
        int price;
}

void changePrice(storeItem item)
{
    int origPrice = item.getPrice();
    item.setPrice(rand() % 10 + 1);
    //The price is correctly changed and printed here.
    cout << "This item costs " << item.getPrice() << " dollars and the price was originally " << origPrice << " dollars." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    storeItem tomato(1);
    changePrice(tomato);
    //This would print out "This item costs *rand number here* dollars and the price was originally 1 dollars." But if I call it again...
    changePrice(tomato);
    //This would print out "This item costs *rand number here* dollars and the price was originally 1 dollars." even though the origPrice value should have changed.
}
```

I'm sure I'm making a silly beginners mistake and I appreciate any help in advance! :)

Comment: Use the reference in your method: `storeItem& item`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass by Reference / Value in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, function parameters are passed by value unless you indicate otherwise. In your example, you are passing the `storeItem` by value to your function, so you are modifying a local copy inside of the function body. There is no effect on the caller side. You need to pass a reference:

```
void changePrice(storeItem& item)
                          ^
```

Semantically, a reference is just an alias for an object, so you can consider the `storeItem` inside of your function to be the same as the one on the caller side.

Answer (score 1):

When calling your function `changePrice` you don't call it by reference, nor with a pointer to the storeItem, so a copy is built.

Call it by reference instead:

```
void changePrice(storeItem& item)
{
     //what you did before
}
```

Refer to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm) for further reference.