# Using input argument as output

Tags: c++, function

my question is:
I saw(in CUDA examples) that it is possible to use one of the input arguments of a function as output variable. Example: add two integers, c=a+b:

```
void function AddT(int a,int b,int c){
   c=a+b;
}
```

But this will not work. The function will not alter the value of c in the main program. Who can I fix it and allow the function to change the value of c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the variable c by reference.

```
void function AddT(int a, int b, int& c)
{
    c = a + b;
}
```

This will make it so that any changes to c that you make in the function will remain even after the function ends.  My wording is pretty poor here; you can look here for more information:

[Pass by Reference / Value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)

[What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value#373429)

Comment: You mean this will make `c` an alias for the passed object, instead of a copy of it, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification.  The argument you pass when calling the function and c will have different variable names, but will both refer to the same object.