# MFC Classes CMAP

Tags: class, dictionary, mfc

```
What I do not understand is the :  “UINT&”.  What does it mean in the context of the template

       static CMap<CString, LPCSTR, UINT, UINT&> cXMLfields::fields_by_name;


       static CMap<CString, LPCSTR, UINT, UINT&> cXMLfields::oopf_fields_by_name;
       static CString friendly_name[XML_FIELDNUM];
       static CString fields_by_id[XML_FIELDNUM];
       static CString oopf_fields_by_id[OOPF_XML_FIELDNUM];
       static void Build_map();
       static void MoveItem(CListBox& src, CListBox& dst, int index);


CMap<CString,LPCTSTR, struct_sample,struct_sample> myMap;
struct_sample aTest;
aTest.a = 1;
aTest.b = 2;
aTest.c = 3;
myMap.SetAt("test",aTest);
    struct_sample aLookupTest;
    BOOL bExists = myMap.Lookup("test",aLookupTest); //Retrieves the 
                             //struct_sample corresponding to "test".
```

I understand the theory, but my key is a String  e.g  “RFIDTAG1”.And my value is an unsigned integer.  Example.UNIT is the Value to the Specific KEY ...for example {Age : 27} Where Age is the Key and 27 is the Value.I struggle when the value is an integer, I can understand if the value was a structure.So Can you use {Age: 27 }  as the example and show me the code like below when using a structure

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. The terrible formatting isn't helping. You've found the [edit] link already; try consulting the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), too.

Answer (score 0):

The & means **pass by reference**.

See this [link](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c&ved=0ahUKEwji-v_CuMHNAhUkBcAKHefdDgIQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNFvk8NbYa3pJuTMfbO_pWLRU3p70A&sig2=D_tlMEkgvcLKGCrpahtZEg).

Also here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z.aspx).

> ARG_VALUE
>
> Data type used for VALUE arguments; usually a **reference** to VALUE.

Comment: I understand the theory, but my key is a String  e.g  “RFIDTAG1”
              And my value is an unsigned integer.  Example.UNIT is the Value to the Specific KEY ...for example {Age : 27} Where Age is the Key and 27 is the Value
 
I struggle when the value is an integer, I can understand if the value was a structure.