# The return value of the function isn't being return

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I need to write a function that accepts an in array and the array's size as argument. The function should create a new array that is twice the size of the argument array. the function should copy the contents of the argument array to the new array and initialize the unused elements of the second array with - . the function should return a pointer to the new array.
So this is the prompt that I need to complete. I get the array that I want in the function but it isn't being brought to the main function.

```
void  moveOver(int *arr, int size)
{
    int *arrp=nullptr;
    arrp= new int[size + 1];
    //arrp[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        arrp[i] = arr[i-1];
    }
    arr = new int[size + 1];
    *arr = *arrp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
        //cout << *(arr+i) << endl;
        cout << arrp[i] << endl;
    }

}
int main()
{
    const int size = 4;

    int arr[size] = { 1,2,3,4 }, *arrptr=nullptr;
    arrptr = arr;
    moveOver(arr, size);
    for (int i = 0; i <=size ; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when it print it prints out only 4 indexes instead of the 5 that I need. any advice would be appreciated. Also I suppose to use pointers and array, I can't use vectors

Comment: Why are you allocating *new* memory for `arr`?  You didn't delete the memory from `arr` before overwriting the previous array.

Comment: BTW, `*arr = *arrp;` only copies the first slot.  You'll need `std::copy` to copy arrays.  Vectors are easier to use.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help, Ron I would love to use vectors but this assignments want us to use arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr` is a local variable inside the `moveOver()` function. Assigning to it has no effect on the variables in `main()`. And in `main()`, `arr` is an array, not a pointer, so you can't reassign it to point to a different array.

You need to change `moveOver()` so it takes a reference. Then you can pass `arrptr` to it, and the function will be able to reassign it.

See [Pass by Reference / Value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)

Another problem you have is that `*arr = *arrp;` doesn't copy the whole array, it just copies the first element of the array. But there's no need to allocate a new array for `arr` at all; you can simply do `arr = arrp;` to copy the pointers.

```
void  moveOver(int *&arr, int size)
{
    int *arrp = new int[size + 1];
    arrp[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        arrp[i] = arr[i-1];
    }
    arr = arrp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
        //cout << *(arr+i) << endl;
        cout << arrp[i] << endl;
    }

}
int main()
{
    const int size = 4;

    int arr[size] = { 1,2,3,4 }, *arrptr=nullptr;
    arrptr = arr;
    moveOver(arrptr, size);
    for (int i = 0; i <= size ; i++) {
        cout << arrptr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't understand that you have to put the '&', I also didn't know that you could both * and & at the same time I thought that would cancel each other out. Thank you for all the help and sorry if I gave you six notification, I accidentally press the enter button twice

Comment: I've added a link to another question that explains the difference between passing by reference and value.

Comment: `*` and `&` only cancel each other when they're used as operators. They have completely different meaning in declarations.

Comment: oh cool Thanks I didn't know that. I will read the link, thank you for explaining it so easily!