# Opencv Mat as parameter of a function

Tags: opencv, matrix, mat

I have a trouble now with opencv Mat.

Here's a function

```
void getMat(Mat a){

   double b[3]={1,2,3};

   a=Mat(3,1,CV_64FC1,b);

}
```

When I use the function in main

```
Mat mat(3,1,CV_64FC1);

getMat(mat);
```

but the result of mat is

```
[-9.255963134931783e+61;
  -9.255963134931783e+61;
  -9.255963134931783e+61]
```

so could someone help me out of the problem?

Thanks very much

Best

Jing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c

Comment: void getMat(Mat& a)

Answer (score 2):

Use reference parameter, and `copyTo` the object;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void getMat(Mat &mat){
   double b[3]={1,2,3};
   Mat _mat(3,1,CV_64FC1,b);
   _mat.copyTo(mat);
}

int main(){
    Mat a;
    getMat(a);
    cout << a <<endl;
    return 0;
}

/*
[1;
 2;
 3]
*/
```

Comment: Thanks very much~ Merry Christmas~

Comment: Merry Christmas ~ (We keep Spring Festival in China