# Overloaded functions neither take objects by value, nor by reference, but take de-referenced pointer to object

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, operators, dereference

**Note upfront:** The problem relates to a vector-class implemented by myself, and has **nothing to do with std::vector**

Consider the following **operator-overloading:**

```cpp
//in the Vector-class(declaration)
friend Vector operator+(const Vector& a, const Vector& b);

//outside the Vector-class(implementation)
Vector operator+(const Vector& a, const Vector&b) {
//...
}
```

It **takes references to two vectors**, and returns their sum.
Now when i try something like the following:

```cpp
Vector foo();
Vector bar();

Vector byVal = foo + bar; //using objects
Vector byRef = &foo + &bar; //using address
```

in both cases my IDE tells me the following:

> expression must have integral or unscoped enum-type

In the second case this makes sense, because i would only pass a yielded pointer when the called function would take a pointer, and for a function that takes a reference, i can pass the object itself, but i don't understand why **just using the object is not possible here.**

What makes it more confusing for me, is that the following **seems to be possible:**

```cpp
Vector* foo = new Vector();
Vector* bar = new Vector();

Vector foobar = *foo + *bar;
```

That is i can use **de-referenced pointers** with the overloaded operator.

What is the cause of this behaviour, and how am i supposed to use my overloaded operator in this case?

Comment: `Vector byRef = &foo + &bar; //by reference` That will pass the addresses of `foo` and `bar` to call the operator function. You seem to have some serious misconception about how reference parameters work.

Comment: The answers already address your problem. Yet, I still would like to recommend the following video to you, for learning about passing values to functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNRju6_yn3o

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i think my problem lied more in the definition of 'passing by reference' vs. 'passing by value' which this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c
helped to make a bit clearer for me.
I edited my question, and hopefully my statements are more correct now.

Comment: @ancientchild I probably should have closed your question as a dupe of the one you linked to, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Vector foo();
> Vector bar();
> ```

These are not variable declarations. These are function declarations. They are functions that return `Vector` and take an empty argument list.

Given that you cannot add functions together, nor can you add function pointers together, `foo + bar` and `&foo + &bar` are both ill-formed.

In order to value-initialise a variable, you can use either of the following:

```
Vector foo{};        // uniform initialsation
auto bar = Vector(); // copy initialisation syntax
```

> I wanted to call the constructor of Vector, that doesn't take any arguments

Indeed. Declaration of a function with no arguments, and a variable declaration with empty initialiser list are ambiguous. This is resolved by a language rule that says if a piece of code could syntactically be either a function declaration or something else, then it is a function declaration.

Comment: Oh, i see, thanks! I wanted to call the constructor of Vector, that doesn't take any arguments, like in the way i am used to calling constructors that take arguments, but instead i declared two functions that return a Vector.

Answer (score 1):

If a function marks a parameter as `&`, then an object passed as argument will be passed by reference. The address of the object is taken *implicitly*, so you don't have to (actually must not) write an `&` before the argument object to be passed.

Note further that `Vector foo();` declares a function, not an object. That's why your compiler complains about both of your calls.

```
Vector operator+(const Vector& a, const Vector&b) {
//...
}

Vector foo;
Vector bar;

Vector byVal = foo + bar; //by reference because parameter in operator + is marked as "call by reference" 
// Wrong: Vector byRef = &foo + &bar;
```

Comment: Note that OP seems to have attempted value initialisation. `Vector foo;` is not value initialisation, but default initialisation instead. This is different if `Vector` is trivially constructible.