# Problem with accessing shared_ptr vector objects

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have a problem with accessing shared_ptr Vector from main.
 My `turnOrder` function takes 2 sharedPtr vectors, combines and sorts them and puts the objects to another vector(`Units`).The problem is, when I test the function using for loops it gives exactly what I want 
but in the int main(), `Units` vector seems empty and when I try to access any object it gives this exit code: " exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) ".

```
void turnOrder( std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Monster>> monsters, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>> heroes,  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>> Units) {

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>> units;

    units.reserve(8);

    units.insert(units.begin(), heroes.begin(), heroes.end());
    units.insert(units.end(), monsters.begin(), monsters.end());
//TESTING INITIAL VECTOR

    for(int i = 0; i < units.size(); i++){
        units[i]->printOut();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < units.size(); i++) {
        units[i]->findSpeedRate();
    }
    struct X{

        inline bool operator() ( const std::shared_ptr<Unit> obj1, const std::shared_ptr<Unit> obj2){
            return(obj1->speedRate > obj2->speedRate);
        }
    };
    std::sort(units.begin(), units.end(), X());

    for(int i = 0; i < units.size(); i++){
        Units.emplace_back(units[i]);
    }

//TESTING ORDERED VECTOR
    for(int i = 0; i < Units.size(); i++){
        Units[i]->printOut();
    }

}


int main(){

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>> Units;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Monster>> monsters;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>> heroes;

    auto crusader1 = std::make_shared<Crusader>(1);
    heroes.emplace_back(crusader1);
//It goes the same with the other objects(monsters and heroes)

    turnOrder(monsters, heroes, Units);
    Units[0]->printOut();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass vectors by reference, not by value. You are modifying *copies* of vectors inside the `turnOrder`. Simply change the declaration to

```
void turnOrder( std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Monster>>& monsters, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>>& heroes,  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>& Units) {...}
```

The difference is `&` for each variable. Also, please refer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c) for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

The other poster has a point about copies but I would take a look at this and say if you are going to populate units in this function why not just return units and remove the units parameter. Then

```
Units=turnOrder(monsters, heroes)
```

makes lots of sense.