# Result of method used to call another method yields inconsistent results?

Tags: c++

I currently have to write a program that allows a user to pick between two objects to test. This isn't the same program exactly but it's the same premise.

class defined by header file

```
#include <iostream>

class example {
private:
    int x;
public:
    example() {
        x = 10;
    }
    void setNum(int input) {
        x = input;
    }
    int getNum() {
        return x;
    }
};
```

Test main and selectObj method

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"



example selectObj(example A, example B) {
    int selection;
    std::cout << "Select object 1 or 2: ";
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> selection;
        if (selection == 1)
            return A;
        else if (selection == 2)
            return B;
        else
            std::cout << "Inavlid option, try again: ";
    }
}



int main() {
    example test1, test2;
    selectObj(test1, test2).setNum(25);
    std::cout << selectObj(test1, test2).getNum();

    return 0;
}
```

selectObj is supposed to return an object. It runs but it isn't doing what setNum is supposed to do.

Suppose you choose option 1 for both calls of selectObj. It looks something like this.

```
Select object 1 or 2: 1
Select object 1 or 2: 1
10
```

It should have printed out 25 but instead, setNum isn't really changing the value of test1.

However, if I write

```
test1.setNum(25);
std::cout << test1.getNum();
```

Then it does indeed set test1's x value to 25.

Again, this isn't exactly like the program I had written (it is changed now and wouldn't like to rewrite that). However, it is an identical representation of the same concept.

Comment: Your `selectObject` function returns a copy (and also takes copies as arguments) - calling `setNum` on the returned value doesn't modify the objects defined in `main` in any way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass by Reference / Value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)

Comment: To work as you expect, `selectObj()` needs to return a reference and, since it is trying to return a reference to objects supplied as arguments, its arguments also need to be passed by reference.    Instead, `selectObj()` is passed both arguments by value (so the objects passed by the caller are copied) and it returns by value (so returns a copy of the object selected).

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `setNum` on the temporary object created by the `return` statement in `selectObj`. That object stops existing as soon as `setNum` returns, so the change is lost.

Imagine if you did this:

```
int selectInt (int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b) return a;
    return b;
}

int a = 3;
int b = 4;
selectInt(a, b)++;
```

This wouldn't modify either `a` or `b`, because what was passed to `selectInt` was two *values*, 3 and 4. And what was returned was a *value*. There is no way this code could modify `a` or `b`. In fact, you could do this:

```
selectInt(1, 2)++;
```

And clearly there is no persistent object that could be modified. If you want to pass objects by reference, you need to do that -- both to and from your function.

Did you mean this?

```
example& selectObj(example& A, example& B) {
    int selection;
    std::cout << "Select object 1 or 2: ";
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> selection;
        if (selection == 1)
            return A;
        else if (selection == 2)
            return B;
        else
            std::cout << "Inavlid option, try again: ";
    }
}
```